# Get deep array element type

Tags: typescript

```js
const data = {
  foo: [{
    x: 1,
    bar: [{
      y: 1
    }]
  }]
}
```

This works fine:

```js
type level1Type = typeof data.foo[0]
```

What is the correct syntax for extracting the type from a deeper element, e.g

```js
type level2Type = typeof data.foo[0].bar[0]
```

This results in `Parsing error: ';' expected.`

https://codesandbox.io/s/ltykm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```js
type Level2Type = (typeof data)['foo'][0]['bar'][0]
// Level2Type = number
```

The difference is that you're looking up a property on the type, not on the actual value. For more details, see the Typescript documentation for the [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).